# Spring Qualifier without if-else

Tags: java, spring, if-statement

I use Spring Framework. I want to make service for create an archive. I have two types of archive. I would like to know another way how to do it not using if-else statement.

Interface

```
public interface Archive {
     public String makeArchive();
}
```

Implements 1

```
@Component
public class ArchiveRAR implements Archive {
    @Override
    public String makeArchive() {
        return "I made archive RAR.";
   }
}
```

Implements 2

```
@Component
public class ArchiveZIP implements Archive {
    @Override
    public String makeArchive() {
        return "I made archive ZIP.";
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class RunnerApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("archiveRAR")
    Archive archiveRAR;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("archiveZIP")
    Archive archiveZIP;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        Report report = new Report("ZIP");
        //HERE
        if ("RAR".equals(report.getType())) {
            System.out.println(archiveRAR.makeArchive());
        } else if ("ZIP".equals(report.getType())) {
            System.out.println(archiveZIP.makeArchive());
        }

   }
}
```

MainApp

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please have a look at the [Spring tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/04/a-quality-qualifier) on how to use a `Qualifier`

Comment: is it mandatory to create 2 beans and use @Qualifier annotation, because u can create 1 bean that handles the types and each can have a specific behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use here factory pattern instead of if-else statement:

```
@Component
public class ArchiveFactory {
    @Autowired
    private Map<String, Archive> archives;

    public Archive getArhive(String archiveType) {
        return archives.get(archiveType);
    }
}
```

By this way your main method will be:

```
@Service
public class RunnerApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ArchiveFactory archiveFactory;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        Report report = new Report("ZIP");
        Archive archive = archiveFactory.get(report.getType());
        System.out.println(archive.makeArchive());
   }
}
```

Of course you need also to define bean of type `Map<String, Archive>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cleaner way to do it without basically `if-else` and `String comparison` if you can decide beforehand which one you would like to use: just pass the appropriate `Archive` reference to the `Report` bean when you create it and also define a method that will generate your archive:

```
@Component
class Report {
     private Archive archive;

     // declare that Archive dependency is required
     @Autowired
     public Report(@Qualifier("archiveRar") Archive archive) {
     // or public Report(@Qualifier("archiveZip") Archive archive) { 
     // depending on which one you would like to inject and use
         this.archive = archive;
     }

     public void generateArchive() {
         archive.makeArchive();
     }
}
```

Also annotate your 2 `Archive` implementations with meaningful qualifier names:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("archiveRar")
public class ArchiveRAR implements Archive {
    @Override
    public String makeArchive() {
        return "I made archive RAR.";
   }
}
```

and

```
@Component
@Qualifier("archiveZip")
public class ArchiveZIP implements Archive {
    @Override
    public String makeArchive() {
        return "I made archive ZIP.";
    }
}
```

The `Service` will now look simpler:

```
@Service
public class RunnerApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Report report;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        report.generateArchive();
   }
}
```

If you need run-time injection, you can get rid of the `if-else` but not `String` value qualifier for the bean, for example by a accessing the `Spring` bean container using `BeanFactory`.

Keep the above code for `Archive` and its implementations and delete the `Report` class which will no longer be used. In the `Service` use this:

```
@Service
public class RunnerApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        String qualifierValue = "archiveRar";
        // or String qualifierValue = "archiveZip";
        Archive archive = beanFactory.getBean(qualifierValue, Archive.class);
        System.out.println(archive.makeArchive());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way..

```
@Component("RAR")
public class ArchiveRAR implements Archive{...}

@Component("ZIP")
public class ArchiveZIP implements Archive {...}
```

And the service class to inject `BeanFactory`

```
    @Service
    public class RunnerApp implements CommandLineRunner {
       @Autowired 
       BeanFactory beans;

@Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
     String archiveType = "ZIP/RAR"; 
     Archive archive = beans.getBean(archiveType,Archive.class);
    archive.makeArchive(); 

}
```